# Copy Test results from VSTS to self-hosted Azure VM

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have configured a private Build agent/self hosted VM in VSTS.

I want to copy all test results for each test case to my self hosted VM. Currently for this I have created Build Pipeline.

In publish test task,has Test result files e.g. .xml file and Search folder as Default source repository path.

[image]

Test case snapshot:
[image]

How can I specify the path of attachment in test case and copy/download artifacts to VM?
Also after processing the attachment, I want to copy the output back to test results.

How can this be achieved?

Any help highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All necessary files are on agent machine (build/deployment agent), so if you run test during release, the test result files will be on that agent machine.

On the other hand, if you can’t use VsTest task to run test, then you can publish test result through Publish Test Result task.

Comment: Thank you Starian Chen. The test plans are created through VSTS portal. There is no visual studio test project. How do I copy my test case results or attachments to self hosted VM. I have modified my question with some snapshot.

Comment: @Amruta Do you associate test assembly to test case?

Comment: No..there are no test assemblies. The testplans, suites are created from VSTS portal. And there is one attachment added to each testcase. I want to copy this test case attachment to my VM. These test cases are not part of any solution.

Comment: @Amruta The attachment is linked to test case? If not, where is the attachment?

Comment: yes..it is attached as an attachment to testcase. snapshot provided in question

Comment: @Amruta You can download the attachment of test case work item through rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/attachments/get?view=vsts-rest-5.0. On the other hand, you need to associate test assembly to test case, then you can run the test automatically.

Comment: Thank you starian. Yes am trying with rest api's now. The rest api link that you have shared has parameter ID that is Attachment ID. Where can I get ID details?

Comment: I tried with getting results for attachment first. GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?api-version=5.0-preview.1...Here Is the Testcase ID means the runId? and the Id displayed in the testresult is testcaseResultId?

Answer (score 0):

The VsTest task will publish the results automatically.

If you're not using VsTest for whatever reason, then using [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=vsts) would be easier. With deployment groups, you don't need to copy files -- the deployment runs directly on the target machines with no intermediary agent machine necessary.